# How to replace " with blank in a string in java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have this string **"Distrik Timur"**. I want to  remove **"**  from this string.

I thought `String value = translatedValue.replace(""","")` will work.But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotation marks need to be escaped: write `translatedValue.replace("\"", "")`.